# How can I conbine tables of the same structure into one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables which have the same structures except for their names. Can I combine them into one? How to design this new table?

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting to permanently merge the tables into a new table, to overcome the obvious design flaw in the current structure?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to images...) And take a look at [mcve].

Comment: @user450201 Do you want to create a new table to store all data in student1 and student2 and moving all data to new table?

Answer (score 1):

Try a union query:

```
SELECT Semeter, Grade FROM Student1
UNION ALL
SELECT Semeter, Grade FROM Student2;
```

If you also want to keep track of the table origin from which each record in the result set came, you may add a computed column:

```
SELECT Semeter, Grade, 'Student1' AS Source FROM Student1
UNION ALL
SELECT Semeter, Grade, 'Student2' FROM Student2;
```

If you want to create a new single table containing the contents of both student tables, then use:

```
CREATE TABLE AllStudents (Semester INT, Grade INT);
INSERT INTO AllStudents (Semester, Grade)
SELECT Semeter, Grade FROM Student1
UNION ALL
SELECT Semeter, Grade FROM Student2;
```

Comment: I mean I don't want use two or more tables to show the same kind of information. How to design a new table which can contain all the information in that two tables?

Answer (score 0):

Insert into table1
select *
from table2;

do some verification

Drop table2;

Answer (score 0):

You can create one table "student" with columns id, student_name, semister, grade.

You can query for "student1" and "student 2" based on student_name column

Answer (score 0):

This keeps all of the columns in your different tables: [**DEMO**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jXiCyTHmGWpUZfQfZRirr9/0)

```
SELECT * FROM student1, student2
```

If **both tables** have the **same column names**, you can union them. This basicially adds the data from student2 to student1:

```
SELECT Semester, Grade FROM student1
UNION ALL
SELECT Semester, Grade FROM student2;
```

Your question is not that precise. How do you want to "combine" them? Just post a picture of your current data table and the result you need.

Answer (score 0):

Create new table to store data from two (or more) different table:

```
    CREATE TABLE students (
    StudentName VARCHAR(50),
    Semester VARCHAR(50),
    Grade VARCHAR(5));
```

Create unique index to make sure that you'll only insert one record once:

```
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UniqueRecords
    ON students (StudentName , Semester);
```

Perform `INSERT IGNORE` from separate tables into new `students` table;

> Note: `INSERT IGNORE` to skip inserting data already exists in the new table (if to perform insert again in the future).

```
    INSERT INTO students (StudentName, Semester, Grade)
    SELECT 'Student1', Semester, Grade FROM student1;

    INSERT INTO students (StudentName, Semester, Grade)
    SELECT 'Student2', Semester, Grade FROM student2;
```